Redshift left outer join with element of a super column
for getting the element data of a super column, I can run query like below:
select order_id, element1.order_attribute_value elem1 from order o, o.order_attribute_grp element1 where element1.order_attribute_type = 'ABC'

However, for the order without order_attribute_type = 'ABC', it won't include in the resultset. How can I do something like left outer join, so that the order without order_attribute_type = 'ABC' will have null at elem1 from the resultset?

I'm trying to figure out the same thing, and unfortunately if you try to left join unnest a SUPER column in Redshift, and want to specify an ON clause to filter the unnested results, you get: ERROR: invalid join condition for SUPER unnest join, the valid join condition for SUPER unnest join is 'ON TRUE' only :(

You will need to left join this with your source table to get the result you desire.  While this syntax looks like a join it is not.  It is an unnesting of array data.  The major difference is that an unnesting only scans the table once while a self join will scan the table twice.
The scan of the table you have will eliminate the data that doesn't satisfy the WHERE clause.  A second scanning of the table is needed to add back in the rows w/o matching super column information.

I found this syntax accidentally by looking at the definition of information_schema.columns, turns out you can unnest and left join without a full blown subquery:
select t.cols, sc::int arrvalue 
from tbl t
left join (tbl s, s.supcol sc) using(pkcol)

